# droidText: How to reduce memory consumption

Tags: android, pdf-generation, heap-memory

While generating pdf it is consuming some 4MB of memory, the application heap size is also increasing,
After pdf is generated the heap size remains the same, if again try to generate pdf the heap size further increases.

Can we make the heap size to decrease after pdf is generated, and is 4Mb of memory consumption is reasonable?

Comment: Freeing the allocations depends on the code you are using as well as the library itself. (Have you called `document.close();`?) Additionally, 4MB is acceptable for generating a PDF file. Consider that the mobile Chrome browser takes 48MB on the SD card and may use that much or more during runtime. (Heck, even the Play Store takes like 30MB+.)

Comment: yes I am calling document.close(), and you are saying 4mb of heap memory consumption is reasonable.

Comment: Yes it is, however using 4MB, then another 4MB, and another, and so on, is not good for consumption. If you set your `document = null` after it's done, then call `System.gc()`, does it free that 4MB?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, by repeating pdf generation process the heap and allocation size is increasing by 1 MB. like at first the allocation size is around 3Mb and while pdf generation it is 6.4Mb, from there it is increasing by 1Mb per three times.